# Pyspark RDD unexpected change in standard deviation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm following Raju Kumar's PySpark recipes and on recipe 4-5 I found that when you do rdd.stats() and rdd.stats().asDict() you get different values for the standard deviation. This goes unnoticed in the book BTW.

Here is the code to reproduce the finding

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()

air_speed = [12,13,15,12,11,12,11]
air_rdd = sc.parallelize(air_speed)

print(air_rdd.stats())
print(air_rdd.stats().asDict())
```

An this is the output

```
(count: 7, mean: 12.285714285714286, stdev: 1.2777531299998799, max: 15.0, min: 11.0)
{'count': 7, 'mean': 12.285714285714286, 'sum': 86.0, 'min': 11.0, 'max': 15.0, 'stdev': 1.3801311186847085, 'variance': 1.904761904761905}
```

Now, I know the stdev on the first case is the "population" stdev formula while the second is the
unbiased estimator of the population standard dev (AKA the "sample standard deviation"). See [an article](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/summarizing-quantitative-data/variance-standard-deviation-sample/a/population-and-sample-standard-deviation-review) for reference. But what I don't understand is why do they change from one output to the other, I mean it looks like
.asDict() should simply change the format of the output, not it's meaning.

So, does anybody understand the logic of this change?

Answer (score 0):

> I mean it looks like .asDict() should simply change the format of the output, not it's meaning.

I doesn't really change the meaning. `pyspark.statcounter.StatCounter` provides both [sample](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/python/pyspark/statcounter.py#L131-L132) and [population](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5264164a67df498b73facae207eda12ee133be7d/python/pyspark/statcounter.py#L124-L125) variant

```py
>>> stats = air_rdd.stats()                                                                             
>>> stats.stdev()                                                                                       
1.2777531299998799
>>> stats.sampleStdev()                                                                                 
1.3801311186847085
```

and you can choose which one should be used when converting to dictionary:

```py
>>> stats.asDict()                                                                                      
{'count': 7, 'mean': 12.285714285714286, 'sum': 86.0, 'min': 11.0, 'max': 15.0, 'stdev': 1.3801311186847085, 'variance': 1.904761904761905}
>>> stats.asDict(sample=True)                                                                           
{'count': 7, 'mean': 12.285714285714286, 'sum': 86.0, 'min': 11.0, 'max': 15.0, 'stdev': 1.2777531299998799, 'variance': 1.63265306122449}
```

Comment: hey, user10938362, thanks for answering and sharing the references, but I still don't understand why the default in air_rdd.stats() is the population standard deviation while the default in air_rdd.stats().asDict() is the sample std dev.